# Creating Observation FHIR Json using hourly data

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have a data in the following format csv format

[image]

where HR is heart rate, O2Sat is Oxygen Saturation, Temp is temperaute, ICULOS as ICU Length of Stay(showing hour number ranges from 1 to 100).

Now, i am trying to convert this to FHIR format. Since All these things come under observation, i am creating an observation template. For each column i am able to find a sample json where i can feed in the value.

I am not really sure how to interpret hourly data in FHIR. EffectiveTime, EffectivePeriod keys are not taking integer values and eventually failing in FHIR validation.

```
{
  "resourceType": "Observation",
  "id": "heart-rate",
  "meta": {
    "profile": [
      "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/vitalsigns"
    ]
  },
  "status": "registered",
  "category": [
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/observation-category",
          "code": "vital-signs",
          "display": "Vital Signs"
        }
      ],
      "text": "Vital Signs"
    }
  ],
  "code": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://loinc.org",
        "code": "8867-4",
        "display": "Heart rate"
      }
    ],
    "text": "Heart rate"
  },
  "subject": {
    "reference": "Patient/example"
  },
  "effectiveDateTime": "1999-07-02",
  "valueQuantity": {
    "value": 0,
    "unit": "beats/minute",
    "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
    "code": "/min"
  }
}
```

Can someone help me with the format to include hourly data and also how the json would be nested with multiple columns present in the figure ?

NOTE: ICULOS - has entry upto 100 hours.. For each hour values are denoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have a separate Observation for each measurement for each hour (with an appropirate effectiveDateTime indicating the specific time of each measurement).  For example, you might have an effectiveDateTime of "1999-07-02T03:57:15" for the first and "1999-07-02T05:01:22" for the next.  If you have no clue what time the measurements were made at and just have an hourly list, then simply go with "1999-07-02T00:00:00", "1999-07-02T01:00:00", etc.

Comment: Exactly. Thats what i did :-)